# How to copy a polyline using an offset?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line

Is there a QGIS functionality or a plugin that I can use to 'move' polylines in a shapefile with a certain offset to the right or left of its original position and save the result in a new shapefile?

(In Avenue I would use: `aPolyline.ReturnOffset(aDistance)` )